# Python Temperature Converter

Tags: python, parameter-passing, converters

I'm working on a python temperature converter. It will convert Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa. I haven't added the if statements yet, or the Celsius to Fahrenheit function yet. But I'm having trouble with this Fahrenheit to Celsius function,

```
def F_C(x):
    x = raw_input("Please Enter A Value")
    x = int(x)
    x - 32
    x * 0.55

answer = F_C(x)
print x
```

for some reason, it only takes the number and splits it in half. If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to return a value from your function.

Comment: Your code should raise a `NameEror`, what do you mean by split it in half?

Comment: It may not matter much, but 0.55 for 5/9 is not even correct to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning a value. Also you are not storing all the computed values back into the variable `x`

```
def F_C(x):
    x = raw_input("Please Enter A Value")
    x = int(x)
    x = x - 32
    x = x * 0.55
    return x
```

You can simplify it to:

```
def F_C():
    x = raw_input("Please Enter A Value")
    return (int(x) - 32)*0.55
```

Comment: +1 you beat me of 23 secs :) and you were correct about the operator. Thank you

Comment: No need to have input x of function.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
def F_C():
    x = raw_input("Please Enter A Value")
    x = int(x)
    x = x - 32
    x = x * 0.55
    return x
```

becuase youre just assigning x the reassigning x

or do this:

```
def F_C():
    x = raw_input("Please Enter A Value")
    x = int(x)
    x = (x - 32)*0.55
    return x

print F_C()
```

you dont need x becuase x is retrieved within the function so you dont need to put it in as an attribute and you have to return something from the function

also you can use `input` intsead of `raw_input` then you dont have to convert it to an int becuase `raw_input` gives back a string while `input` gives back a integer or float

Good Luck with the rest!

Comment: `def F_C(x)` should be `def F_C()`.  The input value is not used by the function, the function gets input from `raw_input(...)`

Comment: ohhh i seee i didnt catch that ok i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is not correct.  No need to have an input to your function. You do need to return the final value.

```
def F_C():
    '''Prompts user for Fahrenheit input, returns Celsius'''
    f = int(raw_input("Please enter a Fahrenheit value: "))
    return (f - 32) * 5./9

>>> print F_C()
Please enter a Fahrenheit value: -40
-40.0
```